# XCode 11.3.1, test runner fails before executing test on CI

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, xcode11.3

I am running iOS tests on CI, using `fastlane scan` for test running, and running 3-6 `XCode 11.3.1` Simulators in parallel.
Sometimes test runner fails before starting test execution.

Error in .xcresult report:
`Showing Recent Issues YandexMoneyUITests-Runner.app (37126) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (Underlying error: Test runner exited before starting test execution.))`

Error in simulator log is:
`Unable to load configuration data from specified path /Users/jenkins/slave/tmp/.derived/Logs/Test/Test-UITestsRegression-2020.12.09_09-02-07-+0300.xcresult/Staging/1_Test/Diagnostics/YandexMoneyUITests-A74D04A4-AA9B-4CDD-A4D0-DBCA2A87D72F/YandexMoneyUITests-48554B7A-D3F2-4E92-8BD1-EFAAE5F7099B/LaunchSessions/14423DD4-FB11-4986-9353-767ED6B3835B/remote-container/tmp/YandexMoneyUITests-14423DD4-FB11-4986-9353-767ED6B3835B.xctestconfiguration;`, because file doesn't exist.
There is no actually existing `Staging` folder in this path.

Error reproduces regularly, but not in 100% cases - some simulators successfully run tests. And for successfully passed tests there are no any `Staging` folder in .xcresult, neither similar error in simulator logs.

What should I do to avoid this error?